# node js websockets used with api

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a node js API built with express. In one of my http endpoints, I would like to accept the request and send it over websockets to another server, and then return a reply. I'm using the [ws library](https://github.com/websockets/ws). The problem is that the websockets communication is not synchronous, so I don't know how to return an answer to the API client. Anyway, this is what I tried but it's not complete:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const uuid = require('uuid');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:7465/');

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

ws.on('open', function open() {
    console.log('connected');
});

ws.on('close', function close() {
    console.log('disconnected');
});

ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
   console.log('Got data from server:');
   console.log(data);
});

app.post('/my-http-endpoint', function (req, res) {
    var payload = JSON.stringify({ body: req.body, requestID: uuid.v4() });

    ws.send(Buffer.from(payload));

    // How to send a reply?
})

app.listen(1337);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to introduce message IDs. Generate them by counting up a number.

Add the following dictionary to your code:

```
let nextMessageId = 1;
const responseCallbacks = {};
```

When you send something (in the `app.post` callback in your case), do the following:

```
const messageId = obtainFreeMessageId(); // see below
ws.send(Buffer.from({ messageId, payload }));
responseCallbacks[messageId] = function(data) {
    // make use of the response message data here
};
```

On message do the following (the response must contain `messageId` as well):

```
const messageId = message.messageId; // message has a message ID
const responseCallback = responseCallbacks[messageId];
if(responseCallback) {
    responseCallback(message.data); // message contains your data
    delete responseCallbacks[messageId];
}
```

Helper function for message ID generation which helps prevent possible overflow:

```
const MaximumMessageId = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF; // 48-bit integer (64-bit is too much for javascript, 32-bit is a little bit too stingy)

function obtainFreeMessageId() {
    const messageId = nextMessageId;
    nextMessageId++;
    if(nextMessageId > MaximumMessageId) {
        nextMessageId = 1;
    }
    return messageId;
}
```

Consider setting a timeout which calls the response callback after a certain amount of time if you want to make sure the request comes to an end. Clear the timeout in the response callback.